# Heroku can't find facebook.yml file; what is going on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, yaml

I am deploying an app that works locally to heroku. My heroku logs produce the following error:

> /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:145:in
>   `initialize': No such file or
>   directory -
>   /app/2c325e9f-adb9-420e-b7d8-a80f8aa4c4e6/home/config/facebook.yml

My facebook.yml file is in the /config directory and is formatted as such:

```
development:

    app_id

    secret_key


test:

    app_id

    secret_key

production:

    app_id

    secret_key
```

Comment: Is it checked in to your git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you forgot to...

```
git add facebook.yml
git commit -m 'new file' .
```

prior to

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it was in my damn git ignore file.

Comment: WARNING!! ouch very bad advise, if you are reading this comment please check the other answer!!

Answer (score 1):

Althouh DigitalRoss answer works may not always be a best practice.

Adding yaml files to repository you put sensitive information into your git account
leaving security issues (eg. if code is shared in github or else).

Here's what [heroku suggest](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).